# Losing variable. Element is undefined in VARIABLES

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

We are getting this error in both ColdFusion 9 and ColdFusion 11 servers in production. I originally thought is related to ColdFusion 9 and JavaHeap space or not enough memory. We moved this process to run on a brand new server (ColdFusion 11) where nothing else is running and has a lot of memory and we still get the error. Here is some of the code for this cfm page:

```
<cfset variables.email_count = 0>
<!--- email notifications --->
<cfoutput query="getOrdersForNotification" group="order_id">

    <cfset variables.inv = "">
    <cfset variables.usePdf = false>
    <cfif isDefined("application.feature_list_using_pdf_attachment")
            and listFindNoCase(application.feature_list_using_pdf_attachment, "injection scheduler", ",")
        >
        <cfset variables.usePdf = true>
    </cfif>

    <cfthread name="InjectionSchdEmail#dateFormat(now(), 'mmdd')#_#timeFormat(now(), 'HHmmss')#_#getOrdersForNotification.order_id#"
        threadOrderId="#getOrdersForNotification.order_id#"
        threadMemberId="#getOrdersForNotification.member_id#"
        threadNotificationEmail="#getOrdersForNotification.notification_email#"
        threadDateReq="#getOrdersForNotification.date_req#"
        threadStoreCode="#getOrdersForNotification.store_code#"
        threadStoreName="#getOrdersForNotification.store_name#"
        threadToGoLabel="#application.togo_label#"
        threadOrderTotal="#getOrdersForNotification.order_total#"
        threadDelTimeValueFront="#getOrdersForNotification.del_time_value_front#"       
        threadSubject="#variables.subjectAndBodyTemplates.subject#"
        threadBody="#variables.subjectAndBodyTemplates.body#"
        threadFromEmail="#variables.fromEmail#"
        threadLocalNow="#variables.localNow#"
        threadLocalNowInt="#variables.localNowInt#"
        threadDs="#ds#"
        threadUsePdf="#variables.usePdf#"
        >
        <cftry>
            <cfset url.order_id = threadOrderId>
            <cfset url.member_id = threadMemberId>
            <cfsavecontent variable="variables.inv">
                <cfinclude template="invoicedeska.cfm">
            </cfsavecontent>

            <cfset variables.order_day=dateFormat(application.UdfService.toSlashDate(threadDateReq), 'mmm dd')>

            <cfset local.subject = threadSubject>
            <cfset local.subject = ReplaceNoCase(local.subject, "[Store Code]", threadStoreCode, "all")>
            <cfset local.subject = ReplaceNoCase(local.subject, "[Takeout Label]", threadToGoLabel, "all")>
            <cfset local.subject = ReplaceNoCase(local.subject, "[Order ID]", threadOrderId, "all")>
            <cfset local.subject = ReplaceNoCase(local.subject, "[Order Total]", NumberFormat(threadOrderTotal,"9,999.99"), "all")>
            <cfset local.subject = ReplaceNoCase(local.subject, "[Required Time]", threadDelTimeValueFront, "all")>
            <cfset local.subject = ReplaceNoCase(local.subject, "[Required Date]", variables.order_day, "all")>

            <cfset local.body = threadBody>
            <cfset local.body = ReplaceNoCase(local.body, "[Store Code]", threadStoreCode, "all")>
            <cfset local.body = ReplaceNoCase(local.body, "[Store Name]", threadStoreName, "all")>
            <cfset local.body = ReplaceNoCase(local.body, "[Order ID]", threadOrderId, "all")>
            <cfset local.body = ReplaceNoCase(local.body, "[Order Total]", NumberFormat(threadOrderTotal,"9,999.99"), "all")>
            <cfset local.body = ReplaceNoCase(local.body, "[Required Time]", threadDelTimeValueFront, "all")>
            <cfset local.body = ReplaceNoCase(local.body, "[Required Date]", variables.order_day, "all")>
            <cfset local.body = "<span style='font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; color: ##000000'>#application.UdfService.multiLiner(local.body)#</span>">

            <cfif threadUsePdf>
                <!--- PDF version --->
                <cfdocument 
                    format="PDF" 
                    name="variables.attachment" 
                    localURL="#application.pdf_localURL#" 
                    orientation="#application.pdf_orientation#"
                    marginleft="#application.pdf_marginleft#" 
                    marginright="#application.pdf_marginright#" 
                    margintop="#application.pdf_margintop#" 
                    marginbottom="#application.pdf_marginbottom#" 
                    unit="#application.pdf_unit#" 
                    scale="#application.pdf_scale#"
                >
                    #variables.inv#
                </cfdocument>
            <cfelse>
                <!--- HTML version --->
                <cfset variables.attachment = variables.inv>
            </cfif>

            <cfmail to="#threadNotificationEmail#" from="#threadFromEmail#" subject="#local.subject#" type="html">
                #local.body#
                <cfif isDefined("variables.attachment") and threadUsePdf eq false>
                    <cfmailparam
                        file="invoice_#threadOrderId#_#threadLocalNowInt#.html"
                        type="application/html"
                        content="#variables.attachment#"
                        />
                <cfelseif isDefined("variables.attachment") and threadUsePdf>
                    <cfmailparam
                        file="invoice_#threadOrderId#_#threadLocalNowInt#.pdf"
                        type="application/pdf"
                        content="#variables.attachment#"
                        />
                </cfif>
            </cfmail>

            <cfset invoice_emailed = application.MessageService.setEmailedInvoice(orderId = threadOrderId, localNow = threadLocalNow, emailAddress = threadNotificationEmail, datasource = threadDs)>

            <cfcatch type="any">
                <cfset variables.attachment = "">
                <cfmail from="erroralerts@monkeymediasoftware.com" to="erroralerts@monkeymediasoftware.com" type="html" subject="POS injection notification email faliure">
                    <cfif isDefined("cgi.server_name")>
                        Server: <b>#cgi.server_name#</b>
                    </cfif>
                    <cfdump var="#cfcatch#" label="cfcatch"><br />
                    <cfdump var="#threadOrderId#" label="threadOrderId"><br />
                    <cfdump var="#threadMemberId#" label="threadMemberId"><br />
                    <cfdump var="#threadNotificationEmail#" label="threadNotificationEmail"><br />
                    <cfdump var="#threadDateReq#" label="threadDateReq"><br />
                    <cfdump var="#threadStoreCode#" label="threadStoreCode"><br />
                    <cfdump var="#threadStoreName#" label="threadStoreName"><br />
                    <cfdump var="#threadToGoLabel#" label="threadToGoLabel"><br />
                    <cfdump var="#threadOrderTotal#" label="threadOrderTotal"><br />
                    <cfdump var="#threadDelTimeValueFront#" label="threadDelTimeValueFront"><br />
                    <cfdump var="#local.subject#" label="local.subject"><br />
                    <cfdump var="#local.body#" label="local.body"><br />
                    <cfdump var="#threadFromEmail#" label="threadFromEmail"><br />
                    <cfdump var="#threadLocalNow#" label="threadLocalNow"><br />
                    <cfdump var="#threadLocalNowInt#" label="threadLocalNowInt"><br />
                    <cfdump var="#threadDs#" label="threadDs"><br />
                    <cfdump var="#threadUsePdf#" label="threadUsePdf"><br />
                    <cfdump var="#variables.inv#" label="variables.inv"><br />
                </cfmail>
                <cfrethrow />
            </cfcatch>
        </cftry>
    </cfthread>

    <cfset variables.email_count = variables.email_count + 1>
</cfoutput>

<p></p><cfoutput>#variables.email_count# emails sent @ #local_now()#</cfoutput>
```

Error:

> Element EMAIL_COUNT is undefined in VARIABLES.
>   The error occurred on line

Comment: Have you tried `request` scope and see if that makes a difference?

Comment: We can definitely try changing it. I want to understand conceptually why we don't have this issue for thousands of other variables and pages in our application.

Comment: Are you inside of a CFC?. If so, can you try `this.` ?

Comment: (Edit) You need to provide more context.  For example, is the above code part a .cfm script, a .cfc, are there any includes involved, that might also modify that variable, etectera? Without knowing more, my "shot in the dark" thought would be race conditions, but again... you need to provide more context.

Comment: I did say it's in a cfm page. In that loop all we are doing is creating a cfthread that does the processing. There is no other code between setting this variable and then using it.

Comment: I second what @Leigh says: we can't sensibly comment on this situation based on half a dozen lines of abstracted code & no context. Also, what troubleshooting have you already done yourself?

Comment: I have added the full block of code for you to review now

Comment: Troubleshoot as follows - first comment out everything between `<cfoutput query="getOrdersForNotification" group="order_id">` and `<cfset variables.email_count = variables.email_count + 1>`.  Run the page.  If it runs successfully, start uncommmenting lines bit by bit until the error recurs.  Then look at the last line you uncommented.

Comment: I think I failed to mention that this code is running hundreds of times per day successfully and the error happens only a couple of times. Also the error would happen for a few different variables on the page.

Comment: That still sounds like race conditions. Especially if the problem variables are all stored in a shared scope like variables. Try passing those values into the thread so they are in the thread local scope instead. If you really must keep them in a shared scope, you may need to add some locking.